# Nginx fallback for file not found to different directory with same path

Tags: angularjs, nginx

**Short Version:** Is there any easy way to automatically redirect a path like **/templates/my_child_theme/main/sidebar/user_nav.html** to **/templates/default/main/sidebar/user_nav.html** whenever a 404 is encountered?

**Question:** Is there an easy way to use something like try_files within nginx to change a filepath when not found to a different folder with the same file path at the end? I'm currently using a client-side framework (AngularJS) and dealing with checking for the existence of files can get fairly expensive as I am literally performing an AJAX call for each file and looking for a 404 before performing the logic to swap out the path in Javascript. I've seen similar solutions for fallback images but haven't gotten a good solution yet. Here's the gist of what I'm looking to do:

1. Look for file at /templates/$1/$2.
2. On HTTP 404 instead return /templates/default/$2.
3. This only really needs to happen in the /templates/ location for now.
4. It's possible that these files could be nested several layers deep so I need something like **/templates/my_child_theme/main/sidebar/user_nav.html** to redirect to **/templates/default/main/sidebar/user_nav.html**

**Backstory:**
I've been building a site in AngularJS that has a fairly complex templating setup. I am utilizing the awesome ui-router module from Angular UI for deeply nested views and have written a few custom functions to implement child themes similar to Magento's fallback system. Here's what currently happens:

AngularJS requests a template path using a getTemplate() function I wrote which first looks for the file at /**templates/child_theme_name_here/filepath** by performing an XMLHttpRequest, checking for a status code of 404 (file not found), and then either returning that path or (in the case of a 404) returning /**templates/default/filepath** instead.

This way I can overload modify specific templates without needing to copy the entire theme each time, making development easier (we have 3 major corporate clients which will each have their own branded child theme) by not making me keep up with each change across multiple themes.

If there is a better way to do this within AngularJS I am open to that as well, it just seemed to me that Nginx would be the most logical place to perform such an action due to to it's low-level integration with the filesystem.

Comment: you are asking for simple solutions, but as i read what you wrote like 'try_files,redirect path' these are all in the nginx documentation or in their wiki on their site. The question is, have you read those and have difficulties? What did you tried until now?(didn't work?)

Comment: I've looked into the try_files documentation quite a bit. Perhaps my questions is aimed more at how to setup the regex needed to get the correct capture groups.

Comment: Finally got it solved. Answer added below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved.**

Had to teach myself a bit on regular expressions, but finally got it working.

Here's what worked:

```
location ~* ^\/templates\/([^\/\\\]+)(.*)$ {
        try_files /templates/$1$2 /templates/default$2 =404;
    }
```

Regex Explanation

- **~*** means case-insensitive matching (not really regex, just nginx syntax)
- **^** means start of a string
- **\/** means match a backslash
  templates means literally match the word templates
- **\/** means match a backslash again
- **(** means start capturing the following match as a group for later use
- **[^\\\/]** means match anything that's not a backslash or forward slash means the previous set of characters can be matched multiple times (i.e. keep matching anything that isn't a slash.
- **)** means stop capturing characters for this group. We have now defined the string that represents the first folder after /templates/
- **(.*)** means match any other character as many times as needed (match everything that isn't a line feed in other words)
- **$** means match the end of the string

try_files then tries each URL in order

- **/templates/$1$2** means try /templates/(everything in capture group 1 above, which holds the folder we captured)(then add everything from capture group which holds the backslash and anything after it until the end of the url)
- **/templates/default$2** is very similar, except instead of using the text from capture group 1 ($1, the folder name we matched) we use the text "default" and then add everything from the second capture group to the end like before
- **=404** means that if neither of those worked return a 404 error

I'm seeing a significant speed improvement by moving this fallback mechanism into the server versus all of the extraneous calls I was forced to do before on the client.